# Break into debugger when object type is queried

Tags: .net, debugging

In COM I can put a breakpoint in QueryInterface to detect when the type of my object is analyzed.  For example, I can put an object between demuxer and decoder in directshow and discover secret protocoll between filters.  Can this be done in .net?  Can I break when code does obj is type?

Comment: Code example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The `is` keyword translates into the `isinst` IL instruction, so there's no managed method you can break on. However, underneath that the CLR translates this into a call to `clr!JIT_IsInstanceOfClass`, so you can place a native break point on that and intercept usage of `is`.